# button is displayed odd on the page using vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to display simple button on the page
My code looks like this

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component("vaadinbasic.VaadinBasicUi")
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class VaadinBasicUi extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Button button = new Button("Click me!");
        button.setWidth("100");
        button.setHeight("50");
        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
               Notification.show("You clicked me!");
           }
        });

        HorizontalLayout mainLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        mainLayout.setSizeFull();
        mainLayout.addComponent(button);
        setContent(mainLayout);
    }

}
```

But the end result looks like this

[image]

The HTML markup for this block looks like this

```
<div class="v-button v-widget v-has-width v-has-height" tabindex="0" role="button" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">
    <span class="v-button-wrap">
        <span class="v-button-caption"></span>
    </span>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: please for future reference, don't add the code as a screenshot, but just add the code to the question.  this makes it impossible for someone to actually try it out. have you tried different themes and browsers?  have you tried looking into the problem with the browser devtools? (e.g. firebug)

Comment: Oops. My bad. I tried. In all browsers I have the same problem.

Comment: please also state the vaadin version and what theme are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the default reindeer theme, which assumes that button's height is undefined. In your markup you define 50px height for your button. The fix is remove the height attribute from the markup or use another theme that supports buttons with different heights.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the theme 
e.g.

```
@Theme("testvaadin")
public class VaadinBasicUi extends UI {
```

Comment: The answer is not really explaining what's the reason for the issue. See my answer for explanation.